# Appending with '+=' in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor

I am trying to build a Calculator using JavaScript and i am using an object oriented approach.
In the constructor function, I have a method that is supposed to display the values of the numbers clicked on screen. In the displayNum method, i used '+=' to append the new number clicked to the already existing numbers but i keep getting 'undefined' before the first number i clicked. For example, if i click 8 and 9, i will get "undefined89". Here is my code

```js
function Calculator(element) {
  this.numberBtns = [...element.querySelectorAll('[data-numbers]')]
  this.firstOperand = element.querySelector('.first-operand')
  this.secondOperand = element.querySelector('.second-operand')

  this.numberBtns.forEach((number) => {
    number.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.displayNum(number.textContent);
      this.updateDisplay()


    })
  })

}

Calculator.prototype.updateDisplay = function() {
  this.secondOperand.textContent = this.currentOperand

}
Calculator.prototype.displayNum = function(number) {
  this.currentOperand += number

}
```

Comment: this.currentOperand is undefined. You have to first define it in your constructor.

Comment: Also, you mention a "constructor function [method]", but in the code provided, you don't seem to have a constructor. More on constructors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor

Comment: Careful `.textContent` probably returns a string, so that `+=` may concatenate strings instead of summing numerical values ('1' + '2' == '12')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i keep getting 'undefined' before the first number

Well yes that's because `this.currentOperand` **is** `undefined` until you create the property. You'll want to initialise it as the empty string in the constructor:

```
this.currentOperand = '';
```